# Save Url of email sent by google app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm currently creating an application with Google App Maker. When I send an email inside the app with Gmail, I want to save the URL of the email to have quick access to the thread of the email. How can I do that?

I've already see this:

The function `sendEmail` inside google app maker doesn't return an url.
I wanted to scrape a gmail page, but with google app maker it's useless.

I've read all the google app maker documentation, but have not found a solution.

Comment: Not sure how the URL to an email will help you, as it is specific to the email account that sent it, and therefore different users would not be able to gain access to it anyways unless they have the credentials to the account that sent it. Otherwise, instead of using the built in MailApp service you may want to look at the Gmail Service instead here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/ and see if you can implement this in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello ! thank you very much to answer my question !

Comment: i will check if i can call google app script inside google app maker thank you very much !

Everyone how use the app have the same address mail and have access to this one.

The Url of the email is used to get to a thread inside google app maker from a button to facilite access to mail management.

Comment: App Maker server scripts are based on Google Apps Script so you should not have any problems from that perspective. I tested using GmailApp as my starting line of code followed by a dot and App Maker appears to pick it up with the intellisense so it should be supported out of the box. I would suggest doing something like this `GmailApp.createDraft().send().getId` and then construct your URL using the Id of the mail message.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working !
:)

Comment: If you found a solution I would suggest posting your solution, so that it may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so like Markus Malessa explained me.

You need to call GmailApp.createDraft().send().getId();

this call will return the id of the email just been sent.

> What gonna happend here is The GmaillApp gonna create a Draft of your email and gonna send it and save the ID of the mail then you can combine a link with the id and when you gonna trying to access this link you gonna have a redirection to Gmail and gonna show the search mail (You have example below).

You can find what parameter createDraft() wait [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String)).

All you need to do is this :

```
var mailId = GmailApp.create().send().getId();
var LinkMail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm#sent/" + mailId;
```

Now you have access to the email just been sent and do what you want !